# How to center image which is bigger than screen?

Tags: html, css, image, center

I've following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
    <img src="banner.png">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner > img {
    margin: auto;
}
```

The Image have a width of 3000px and a height of 200px
I want the image horizontal centered and no horizontal scroll bar.
(Browser resizing should no problem then)

I've tried to give the `.banner` div the banner image as background-image but then the div won't find it's size automatically ...

How is this possible?

Comment: If you set a background then you can use a 30x2 transparent image and set it to width 100% so it will take up the correct amount of space for the div

Comment: possible duplicate of [center oversized image in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562457/center-oversized-image-in-div)

Comment: If you need to use an `<img>`, look at the duplicate I've marked this as. If you can use a background image, try doing [`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) with a CSS background image

Comment: The answer of nicogaldo describe what i was searching, but thanks. It's also very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is using the images as background, but if you want/need to use the image, do it like this

```
.banner{overflow:hidden; height:200px; width:100%; text-align:center;}
.banner img{width:100%; height:100%; margin:0 auto;}
```

Comment: I don't want to set the exact size og the image in css. Should be dynamically

Comment: you mention fixed sizes in your post. Anyways, for that, the better way is to use the image as background as I mentioned and other people did

Answer (score 3):

## How to Center an Image in HTML & CSS and prevent horizontal scroll bar?

### 1. Prevent horizontal scroll bar:

Try this will work perfectly, add `overflow-x`property to the class and set it to `hidden`, That Will Disable The Horizontal Scroll Bar in CSS. See [How to prevent horizontal scrolling? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13368425/19211526).

### 2. How to Center an Image in CSS?

You can center the image by using these CSS properties:

1. `display: flex;`.
2. `justify-content: center;`.

##### CSS code:

```css
.banner {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

##### HTML code:

```html
<div class="banner">
    <img src="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="banner">
</div>
```

css:

```
.banner {
    background: url(http://ximg.es/3000x200/000/fff.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    height:200px;
}
```

like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicogaldo/6fgmhw1q/)

Comment: But instead of `50% 50%` i used `center`